# how to refresh a portion of a page in intervals

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that above it I want to have a panel that automatically refresh every 5 minutes, and if a user has a message in his inbox show to him. What is the best solution for this?

Should I usel AJAX, jQuery, or JavaScript? My preferred solution is server side solution.

Comment: why was this downvoted? not a bad question at all. +1 to level it out.

Comment: I got this habit for users that vote me down with no reason

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - agreed. But i've seen worse ones with a reason for the downvote. SO really should track people who downvote with no comment, and should point them out somehow. That would stop em. :)

Comment: I agree with @RPM1984 I post a topic on `StackExchange` for this,but users vote to close that topic.I said SO force users to say a reason for vote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with ASP.Net, you can also achieve this behavior by using a combination of the following:

1. [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) or [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) (if you have nested pages):
   Manages the ajax calls
2. [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx): Determines **what** gets updated.  Controls nested within `<ContentTemplate>` are subject to partial
   updates
3. [Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers): Controls **when** the content is updated.

For your purpose, a `Timer` control can be used as a trigger to ensure that partial postbacks are triggered every 5 seconds:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerMain" runat="server"/>
<asp:Timer ID="timer" Interval="5000" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelToBeUpdated" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Jquery to send an AJax request to the server to fetch the updated content. Upon receiving the content I would use JQuery again to update the markup.

You can set this up to trigger every 5 min using setInterval in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give a specific example without code. But you basically need to load the new content with an ajax request that is triggered by a timer.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "someUrlThatServesUpdatedContent.aspx",
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#results").html(html);
    });
}, 300000);
```

The above is just a simple example to point you in the right direction.

Edit: Here is an example of how to do the ajax call without JQuery
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792721/1059001

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do that with AJAX using method described by previous answers, but if you wish to have a server side solution I would recommend loading that part of the page in an iframe, with meta refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

This method however would make it difficult to communicate any events or user actions back to main page.

Comment: This isn't a "server side solution" since it relies on the browser to reload the iframe. It isn't really possible to have an entirely server side solution on the web, since the server can't trigger the browser to do anything directly.

Comment: can I use a user control and use your `Meta tag` in it? and add it to my page?